# Creating RxJava Flowables for later chaining

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm relatively new to reactiveX, I think I've picked up most of the fundamentals but one aspect I'm struggling to see is how to create several separate flowables (say inside separate business logic components) and then wire them together later.

Looking through the documentation, I thought FlowableProcessor was what I was looking for, but none of the subclasses are actually helpful. The closest is PublishProcessor except it explicitly states it doesn't properly aggregate downstream backpressure requests. UnicastProcessor also doesn't propagate backpressure, just buffering indefinitely, and the other 3 have 'interesting' behaviour that makes them unsuitable.

Flowable.publish() produces a multicast flowable that's able to aggregate downstream backpressure, but I can't see a way to create one that I can later feed from an upstream flowable. Am I missing something, or is this simply not something that the framework provides out of the box?

Comment: what do you mean by 'wire them together' later? can you give some example of use case? generally speaking, for 'wiring' Flowable together you have many operators.

Comment: Could you provide some examples? FlowableProcessor aside, the only ways to create a Flowable seems to be from Flowable.create/generate/just/only/etc (at which point they'll emit their own values and you can't put them in the middle of a processing chain), or by using an operator on an existing flowable (which doesn't satisfy the 'wire it up later' part).

If I use a FlowableProcessor, I can create that whenever, and at some point down the line subscribe something to it, and subscribe it to something and create a processing chain, but none of them seem to support proper backpressure

Comment: well, for example, if I have 2 separate Flowables and I want them to run one after the other I can use Flowable.concat(flowableA, flowableB), and there are plenty more options using other operators, for instance for 'putting them in the middle of processing chain' you can use flatMap(), that's why I ask for specific scenario

Comment: But here's the difference - with using PublishProcessor as an example, I can create a flowable inside component A, separately create a Publish Processor as part of a component B, separately create another as part as C, and a subscriber as part of component D. At some point after instantiating all these I can connect those 4 together into a single big long chain using the processors as 'terminals'  (and I can throw additional operations in between them as I wire them up but that's not relevant). I can't see a way to acccomplish this with the operators you describe

Comment: Stewart, your problem certainly doesn't seem out of the realm of being solvable simply by Rx. However, I fear it isn't possible to guide you to a correct, idiomatic, and simple solution without just a little bit more information about the problem at hand you're trying to solve. I've found when seeking help with modeling Rx, it's easiest to describe the problem you're trying to solve in plain English. That would at least help me better help you.